# Using two Object Contexts?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I created two edmx files and have to contexts.

Is there a problem with doing something like:

```
public DataManager
{
  protected ObjectContext _context;

  public DataManager(ObjectContext context)
  {
     _context = context;
  }
}
```

or is it better to have an overloaded construtor:

```
public DataManager
{
  protected db1entities _context;
  protected db2entities _context2;

  public DataManager(db2entities context)
  {
     _context = context;
  }

  public DataManager(db2entities context)
  {
     _context2 = context;
  }
}
```

I noticed if I do it the first way, then the context does not know about my entities, where as it does if I explicitly specify the context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but you could also do this using generics ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).  Something like...

```
public class DataManager<T> where T:ObjectContext
{
  protected T _context;

  public DataManager(T context)
  {
     _context = context;
  }
}
```

Then ...

```
DataManager<db1Entities> DataManager1;
DataManager<db2Entities> DataManager2;
```

Comment: I believe this is it. I will test it out, but basically I am just trying to pass a different context depending on what data I want to work with. Would you do me a favor and explain what T means?

Comment: This is a generic class. T stands for the type being used. In this case it specifies that T needs to be of type ObjectContext or classes that inherit from it.

Comment: Like bcr said, T is sort of a placeholder for the type you specify when creating the class.  The expression T:ObjectContext just limits the types you can use with this class to those of type ObjectContext of a child of that class.  Basically, it just stops you from using a completely inappropriate datatype with this class.

Comment: ok, so if I removed the Where, T Could be anything, so it is like a constraint.

Comment: Yes.  With out it, you could say DataManager<TextBox> DataManager1;.  That obviously makes no sense.